# Load file lines into an array AFTER the file is open and locked (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, file-io

Is there a quick way to load every line of a file into an array from a file once it has already been opened?

For example:

```
$handle = fopen("file", "r+");
flock($handle, LOCK_EX);
$array = load_lines($handle);   <- need this
// compute on the array
fwrite($handle, $array);
flock($handle, LOCK_UN):
fclose($handle);
```

The reason I need this is because I currently use the file() function to grab the contents of a file and put them into an array. However, I need to incorporate file locking into my design and I'm hoping to not have to change it too much (it is current array-based). Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use `file()` after you lock it?

Comment: I was thinking about that, but I'm not sure how that works if my file is locked. Technically, I have a stream with the file open, wouldn't file cause another read request which would hang?

Comment: Why not consider use a database for lock handling?

Comment: @ajreal: I've considered it, but I've never used it before. Right now I'm using flat files everywhere and eventually I would like to migrate to a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On php <5.3, or if you choose to with LOCK_NB, file locks in php are advisory.  That is, you have to test the lock yourself .. they don't actually prevent you from updating the file.  This will do:

```
$fh = fopen(__FILE__, 'r+');
if (flock($fh, LOCK_EX)) {
   $array = file(__FILE__);
   fwrite($fh, implode($array));
   flock($fh, LOCK_UN);
   flcose($fh);
}
else {
   echo "Could not acquire the lock!"
}
```

I also tested this out in php 5.3.  It seems that `file()` ignores locking.

Comment: So if it ignores the locking, it should be safe to use? I'm looking for 100% reliability.

Comment: @MaxMackie the script above works as expected in 5.3.6.  The above script should also be compatible with lower versions of php.  In 5.3, the script will block on the `flock()` line (if you don't use non-blocking, see php.net for more info) and continue normally once it can acquire the lock.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function load_lines($handle)
{
    $array = array();

    while(!feof($handle)
    {
        $array[] = fgets($handle);
    }

    return $array;
}
```